# web methods 6.5 schedulers missing after IS restart

Tags: integration, middleware, webmethods

We have a problem with our web methods Integration servers and when we perform restart each time, the schedulers have either been changed or missing. When we compare the jobs.cnf file inside IntegrationServer/config folder, before and after each restart, we can see that the file has been changed. 
What is the best way to handle this problem? Is there anything that web methods provide for us to do a restart without this happening?

Comment: First, 3 questions:

The restart you do is via Shut Down and Restart > restart? or you performing kill to process?

You are running the webMethods on a windows or unix ?

What kind of changes you see in the file?

Comment: 1. its a kill or kill -9 - reason - graceful shutdown doesn't respond

2. running WM on unix

3. specially lot of changes in she schedulers - specially scheduler cnf file - we came across that lot of scheduler jobs have been missing once a restart has been completed. For the time being, we keep a backup of the scheduler config file before a restart and compare it with conf after restart.

Comment: The user that you are using to start the process have full permission of the folder where the Integration Server is installed?

do you have configured the pools for ISInternal & ISCoreAudit? If the dbpool is configured, you have it shared between one or more Integration Servers? Im saying that because we had a situation like that in the past.

Comment: the user has full permission
we have not configured pools for SInternal & ISCoreAudit
Db pool is shared between more Integration servers

Comment: I belive you should try configure the pools for xref, iscore, and isinternal for each server individualy if they are not running as a cluster.

If running as a cluster, you should configure. Im on vacatios now, so i quite dont remember which pool stores the schedule configuration. But you should look for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember, a few years back, we had the same exact problem. I can't remember if we fixed it with a patch or if it simply stopped happening after we upgraded webmethods. 6.5 is quite old.